# Ruby Kafka Producer BufferUnderflow

Tags: ruby, apache-kafka

I wanted to use the ruby kafka client library for producing events, but have come up against a problem that I am not sure how to solve. Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried using kafka-rb (acrosa, mheffner and bpot forks). The problem is that no matter what I send to it via the library e.g.

```
require 'kafka'
host = 'localhost'
port = 9092
producer = Kafka::Producer.new(

        :topic => 'login',
        :host => host,
        :port => port
)
producer.send([Kafka::Message.new("aaaaa")])
```

I get a:

```
java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
    at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.get(HeapByteBuffer.java:127)
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.get(ByteBuffer.java:675)
    at kafka.api.ApiUtils$.readShortString(ApiUtils.scala:22)
    at kafka.api.ProducerRequest$.readFrom(ProducerRequest.scala:34)
    at kafka.api.RequestKeys$$anonfun$1.apply(RequestKeys.scala:34)
    at kafka.api.RequestKeys$$anonfun$1.apply(RequestKeys.scala:34)
    at kafka.network.RequestChannel$Request.<init>(RequestChannel.scala:48)
    at kafka.network.Processor.read(SocketServer.scala:321)
    at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:231)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

on the server. On the same server I can send text through the provided console producer without any issues.

If you have seen this before I would appreciate the help. 
As I am not very familiar with Scala, I am not sure what the problem is, but it seems to me that the line where this exception is thrown, has to do with reading the clientId from the socket, and it also seems to me that there is no such thing sent from the ruby client.

When I look at the messages produced on tcpdump form kafka-rb and the provided producer. The ruby ones seem shorter.
Additionally it does not matter whether I use kafka-0.7 or 0.8, i get the exact same behaviour.

Comment: It turns out that I was using 0.8 in all my attempts as the kafka-rb does not support the 0.7 format. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could reproduce your error with Kafka 0.8 but when I try this implementation:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'kafka'
producer = Kafka::Producer.new({ :host => "localhost", :port => 9092, :topic => "test" , :compression => 0 })
message = Kafka::Message.new("some random message content")
producer.send(message)
```

it works with Kafka 0.7:

[image: consumer example]

According to the Kafka documentation, the client you mentioned is only supported for 0.7.x (https://cwiki.apache.org/KAFKA/clients.html#Clients-Ruby). The 0.8 section says:

> The 0.8 release changes the protocol fairly substantially. This version hasn't been released yet. The new protocol is documented here. A number of clients are in progress, and we will update when they are complete.

So I think https://github.com/acrosa/kafka-rb will not work in this case :-(.

Best

pre

Comment: Looks like I was trying to use kafka-rb with 0.8 even when I thought I was using it with 0.7 (which works). Thanks

Comment: Mind you the built in Zookeeper does not work in 0.7